# How to respond to a http CONNECT request?

Tags: sockets, http, proxy

I want to create a proxy in kotlin with sockets. I created a socket server which connect the client (google.com) to a socket. The http request from Google is:

```
CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com:443
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
```

So I send to the socket:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
Connection: close
```

Then Google sends:

```
; 7����r���9 ����l&�����cO��9���� �.rW�Vs9�T���}�$_aX�ys��&�X "���+�/�,�0̨̩�� � � / 5 
 ���        www.google.com   �   
 
zz       #     hhttp/1.1       
      3 + )zz     
(��>�%܇�    �fT5
��5��ue�u��` -  + 
**   ZZ   ) � � +c���>L����#9�����'���Ʌͩ�5��h�Bn��O�G)��    ����f�^���S�d|bC�7VT5�:���^�QSRך`MM�g#�[�|\�T�9h@�K:7?��t��49   �;`�ʛ�"��ٹ��9����H�f�@��=�����2���(��T)B�`�#�nhS���!뷊��E�ao����/z)e��}���,>�����G��B�� ! ��OF�p�-�>q
```

I send these bytes with a new ssl socket to the domain `google.com` and the port `443`, but this is not working. The response is:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 54
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 31 Aug 2019 14:16:46 GMT

<html><title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title></html>
```

My code:

```
fun createServerSocket() {
 println("Starting Server")

        val server_socket = ServerSocket(555)

        Thread{
            val connection_socket = server_socket.accept()
            //connection_socket.soTimeout = 2000
            _handleConnectionSocket(connection_socket)
        }.start()
    }

private fun _handleConnectionSocket(client_socket: Socket) {
        Thread{
            val client_inputStream = client_socket.getInputStream()
            val client_outputStream = client_socket.getOutputStream()
            val client_bufferedWriter = BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(client_outputStream))

            val ssf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() as SSLSocketFactory
            val server_socket = ssf.createSocket("google.com", 443)
            val server_inputStream = server_socket.getInputStream()
            val server_outputStream = server_socket.getOutputStream()

            var should_save = false
            Thread{
                try {
                    val buffer = ByteArray(4096)
                    do {
                        val read = client_inputStream.read(buffer)
                        if (should_save) {
                            if (read > 0) {
                                server_outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read)
                                if (client_inputStream.available() < 1)
                                    server_outputStream.flush()
                            }
                        }
                    } while (read >= 0)
                } catch (e: java.net.SocketTimeoutException) {}
            }.start()
            Thread.sleep(1000)

            should_save = true
            val client_success_response =
                """
                HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
                Connection: close
                
                """.trimIndent()

            client_bufferedWriter.appendln(client_success_response)
            client_bufferedWriter.flush()

            Thread.sleep(800)
            try {
                val buffer = ByteArray(4096)
                do {
                    val read = server_inputStream.read(buffer)
                    if (read > 0) {
                        client_outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read)
                        if (server_inputStream.available() < 1)
                            client_outputStream.flush()
                    }
                } while (read >= 0)
            } catch (e: java.net.SocketTimeoutException) {}

            println("Fertig")
        }.start()
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that what you describe is not what you actually do. Please show the actual code. And note that these are binary data (TLS handshake and encrypted data) so they should be treated as binary both in your code and in your question (i.e. it makes no sense to include these as text, for displaying encode the data as hex). Also, you seem to mix up client and server: The CONNECT is sent by the client (browser) not google. Similar the binary output is from the client not google.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If this is the handshake, how I can get the request from google?

Comment: There is no *"request from google"*. In HTTP (and HTTPS) the client (browser) sends the **request** and the server (google) sends the **response** after it got the request from the client. But in case of CONNECT you just create a tunnel between client (browser) and server (google) and forward all data unchanged from client to server and server to client. The only HTTP request you deal with is the CONNECT request from client to proxy and the only HTTP response is the one the proxy sends to the client. From then on everything just gets forwarded by the proxy.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. How I get the request from the browser e.g. for a Google search?

Comment: I added my Code

Comment: I think you get the idea how CONNECT works completely wrong. The client (browser) sends a CONNECT request to the proxy which includes the hostname and port it likes to connect to. The proxy creates a TCP (not SSL) connection to the requested server. If this connection is successfully established the proxy sends the `HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established...` response to the browser. From then on the proxy will simply forward all data between client and server in both directions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed the ssl socket to a tcp socket and everything works fine. Please put this comment as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code it looks like you got the idea how CONNECT works wrong. It should work as follows:

1. The client (browser) sends a CONNECT request to the proxy which includes the hostname and port it likes to connect to.
2. The proxy creates a TCP (not SSL as in your case) connection to the requested server.
3. If this connection is successfully established the proxy sends the `HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established...` response to the browser.
4. From then on the proxy will simply forward all data between client and server in both directions.